# Convolution algorithm for image processing

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I've come up with this code for applying a 3x3 kernel to my image:

```
    double sum;

        for(int i = 1; i < src.rows - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < src.cols - 1; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k ++) {
                sum = 0.0;
                dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = 0.0;
                for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++){
                    for(int y = -1; y <=1; y++){
                        sum += (Kernel_Matrix[y+1][x+1]*src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i - x, j - y)[k]);
                    }
                }
                dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(sum);
            }
        }
```

Now I got 2 questions:

1. By reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing), there's various matrix for various filter, let's say I want my Blur filter to increase intensity, via a gui Slider that gives a value from x to whatever, what kind of operation should I make to my Blur Matrix(make a sum, a multiplication...)?
   (I wold like to do the same with sharpness)
2. is there a specific matrix for Noise Reduction?

If you also have any mods to suggest me on my algorithm please let me know!
thanks!

Comment: The Gaussian filter can be used for blurring. Noise reduction is a complex topic, there is no single matrix that will remove it perfectly.

Comment: @Quimby thanks for that, and what if I want to Blur more, via increasing just one value?

Comment: You can do that by increasing the kernel size and the std.dev. of the gaussian distribution. OpenCV already has a kernel for this  - [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html).